# How to insert [Spatial Point] values with a query in MySQL in Laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, geolocation, geometry, point

I have a table with a column of type Spatial point ,,

I want the query to insert the values of that column with laravel

and if there a queries to get items within a specific range ?

any help here ??

That's my table here :

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('markers', function(Blueprint $table)
    {
        $table->integer('marker_id')->primary();
        $table->string('marker_name', 45);
        $table->timestamp('created_at')->default(DB::raw('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'));
    });
    DB::raw("ALTER TABLE markers ADD COLUMN location POINT");
}
```

Comment: insert single value?post your table and code

Comment: I edited my question with the table ,,

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can insert data as follows:

```
ModelName::firstOrCreate(
    array(
        ..//other fields
        'location' => DB::raw("(GeomFromText('POINT(37.774929 -122.419415)'))")
    )
);
```

To retrieve data:

```
SELECT X(`location`), Y(`location`) FROM markers;
```

I too was stuck here & got help from: [Spatial Point functions using Laravel Eloquent ORM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28878862/spatial-point-functions-using-laravel-eloquent-orm). Hope this helps.

Comment: As a side note. I got the error `GeomFromText does not exist`. So I had to change it to `ST_GeomFromText`