# Spatial Point functions using Laravel Eloquent ORM

Tags: mysql, laravel, geometry

I get **longitude and latitude** and want to store the location with
**[Spatial Point]** with **mysql**,,

what's the queries and functions that can help me to insert the values ..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use DB::raw() to do this:

```
    DB::table('table')->insert([
        'field' => DB::raw("SPECIAL_FUNC(X)"),
    ]);
```

Examples:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/point-property-functions.html
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/populating-spatial-columns.html

Comment: @MahmoudNassar Updated answer with links. They are findable using Google BTW.

Comment: Is using Query Builder the only solution?! I want to use Eloquent ORM is there any way?

Comment: Ok I could Solve it using ORM with that :

$location = DB::raw("(GeomFromText('POINT(37.774929 -122.419415)'))");
$newItem->Item_location = $location;
$newItem->save();

Comment: Query Builder and Eloquent Builder have almost the same features and in many cases can be addressed universally.

Comment: I want a query that to retrieve all items within specific rang ,,

I receive the longitude & latitude and have to return all items within 10 m of that location !!

Comment: @MahmoudNassar http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21168380/use-mysql-spatial-extensions-to-select-points-inside-circle